# I can't execute a cordova callback multiple times

Tags: java, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I develop an ionic-cordova project. I need execute a cordova callback more than once.

Here is my Component codes:

```
let data =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.someOptions)) 
    this.customService.TestFunction(data).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
      .catch(ex => {
       // console.log(ex)
      })
  }
```

Here is my CustomService

```
 TestFunction(arg1: any): Promise<any> {
        var temp = cordova(this, "TestFunction", { callbackStyle: "object" }, [arg1]);
        return temp
    }
```

Here is js code

```
exports.TestFunction = function (arg0, success, error) {
    exec(success, error, 'SomeCordovaPlugin', 'TestFunction', [arg0]);
};
```

Here is Java codes for android

```
  public class SomeCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

  private CallbackContext testCallbackContext;

  @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
       if (action.equals("TestFunction")) {
           this.TestFunction(args, callbackContext);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
  }

  private void TestFunction(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
     testCallbackContext=callbackContext;
     if (args != null) {
       try {
           for(int i=0;i\<7;i++){
                 PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK ,testCallbackContext.getCallbackId());
                 pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true); // keep callback
                 testCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);  
            }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
                 testCallbackContext.error("An error occured:" + ex);
                }
     }
  }

}
```

I want to call cordova exec more than once. pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true) is not work for me. I am using ionic 6 and cordova 11. How can I call cordova  exec more than once?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me (except for `\<`). Did you try debugging your code? Are you using a promisify function? You'd rather use an Observable

Comment: I mean, promises are meant to be executed only once.  You should return a raw callback or an Observable

Comment: cordova exec return always a promise. I couldn't find how the observable is returned. Is there a way return observable from cordova exec function?

Comment: I'm not an expert, my `cordova.exec` returns a callback and I wrap it in a Promise. I suppose it's something in new versions because I'm not aware of it

Comment: The [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/#the-javascript-interface) about cordova 11 say that `cordova.exec` accepts two callbacks. Why don't you try `cordova.exec` in place of `cordova()`?

Comment: I have tried but there is no difference between  cordova.exec and cordova(). Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you have a custom cordova plugin which you call from your js side.
You then want to return results from your plugin to the js world multiple times and not just once.

The problem is that the lifecycle of your plugin invocation is completed by calling `sendPluginResult()`

I have solved this by not using `sendPluginResult()` to transfer my return values to JS but calling a JS function directly via the WebView:

**1.** In JS set a custom function which will be called from your plugin with your result values on the object of your custom plugin like:

```
cordova.plugins.<pluginPackage>.<CustomPlugin>.<CustomCallbackFunction> = (data) => {
 //your JS side processing of data returned from your plugin more than once
}
```

With your values for   and

**2.**  Persisting your callbackContext in your custom Plugin to finally finish the call as you already do by calling `sendPluginResult()`

**3.**
Upon invocation of your plugin function dont't call `sendPluginResult()` but instead directly prompt the webview to process JS code where you call your previously in 1. defined callback Function
`webView.sendJavascript("cordova.plugins.<pluginPackage>.<CustomPlugin>.<CustomCallbackFunction>('" + <your payload as JSON string> + "')")` (Kotlin code)

**4.** Finally when you are finished calling your callback multiple times call `sendPluginResult()` on your persisted callbackContext status OK to finish the plugin invocation.

Comment: Can I use  this logic for  observable data ? So I get a continuous data from plugin and I processing this data. Can I return Observable from plugin and subscibe to it in ionic side?